# SAPUI5 table with multiple selection error in getting selected row data

Tags: javascript, html, xml, sapui5

I am using following code to get the data of selected row in table. This code is working fine only when I select the first row.
If I select any row other then first row, Then it gives following error.
Unable to get property 'getObject' of undefined or null reference
at following line
var selectedRowdata = oTable.getSelectedContexts()[i].getObject();

```
var oTable = this.getView().byId("myTable");
var aItems = this.getView().byId('myTable').getItems();
                var aSelectedItems = [];
                for (var i=0; i<aItems.length;i++) {
                     if (aItems[i].getSelected()) {
                       var items= "";
                       var selectedRowdata = oTable.getSelectedContexts()[i].getObject();
                       aSelectedItems = selectedRowdata;
                       var soid = "";
                       var soid1 = "";
                       soid = aSelectedItems['Vbeln'];
                       var n = soid.length;
                       soid = soid1.concat(soid);
                       var tenure = prompt("Are you sure you want to release Sales Order", soid);
                       if (tenure != null) {
                         var oEntry = {};
                         oEntry.Ebeln = soid;
                        var omd =  this.getView().getModel();

                         omd.read("/VBAKSet(Vbeln='"+soid+"')", oEntry, null,
                             function(){alert("updated successfully");},
                             function(){alert("Error in updating data");});
                       }


                            alert("Sales order " + soid + " release successfully" );
                        }

                     }
                };
```

Comment: Why do you loop at `getItems`? Simply loop at `getSelectedContexts`. The error message very cleary tells you what went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
 var selectedItems = oTable.getSelectedItems();

 for (var i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++) {
    var item = selectedItems[i].getBindingContext().getObject();
    //... (default i.e. un-named model assumed)
 }
```